# angularjs directive is not rendered in browser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using this timepicker-popup directive from github:

https://github.com/mytechtip/timepickerpop

I am using it in my html:

```
<timepicker-pop input-time="activeStep.timeTest"
                class="input-group" show-meridian='showMeridian'>
</timepicker-pop>
```

I do not understand, why the timepicker is not even initialized nor rendered.

I am new to the directive stuff but when the directive is named: 'timepickerPop' how can it be that the demo here: https://github.com/mytechtip/timepickerpop/blob/master/demo/timepickerpop-demo.html

uses in the html this format  ????

What do I wrong? I get no errors in my browser console!

```
/**
 * Anularjs Module for pop up timepicker
 */
angular.module('timepickerPop', [ 'ui.bootstrap' ])
.factory('timepickerState', function() {
  var pickers = [];
  return {
        addPicker: function(picker) {
            pickers.push(picker);
        },
        closeAll: function() {
            for (var i=0; i<pickers.length; i++) {
                pickers[i].close();
            }
        }
    };
})
.directive("timeFormat", function($filter) {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    require : 'ngModel',
    scope : {
      showMeridian : '=',
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var parseTime = function(viewValue) {

        if (!viewValue) {
          ngModel.$setValidity('time', true);
          return null;
        } else if (angular.isDate(viewValue) && !isNaN(viewValue)) {
          ngModel.$setValidity('time', true);
          return viewValue;
        } else if (angular.isString(viewValue)) {
          var timeRegex = /^(0?[0-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] ?[a|p]m$/i;
          if (!scope.showMeridian) {
            timeRegex = /^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/;
          }
          if (!timeRegex.test(viewValue)) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('time', false);
            return undefined;
          } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity('time', true);
            var date = new Date();
            var sp = viewValue.split(":");
            var apm = sp[1].match(/[a|p]m/i);
            if (apm) {
              sp[1] = sp[1].replace(/[a|p]m/i, '');
              if (apm[0].toLowerCase() == 'pm') {
                sp[0] = sp[0] + 12;
              }
            }
            date.setHours(sp[0], sp[1]);
            return date;
          };
        } else {
          ngModel.$setValidity('time', false);
          return undefined;
        };
      };

      ngModel.$parsers.push(parseTime);

      var showTime = function(data) {
        parseTime(data);
        var timeFormat = (!scope.showMeridian) ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm a";
        return $filter('date')(data, timeFormat);
      };
      ngModel.$formatters.push(showTime);
      scope.$watch('showMeridian', function(value) {
        var myTime = ngModel.$modelValue;
        if (myTime) {
          element.val(showTime(myTime));
        }

      });
    }
  };
})

.directive('timepickerPop', function($document, timepickerState) {
      return {
        restrict : 'E',
        transclude : false,
        scope : {
          inputTime : "=",
          showMeridian : "=",
          disabled : "="
        },
        controller : function($scope, $element) {
          $scope.isOpen = false;

          $scope.disabledInt = angular.isUndefined($scope.disabled)? false : $scope.disabled;

          $scope.toggle = function() {
            if ($scope.isOpen) {
                $scope.close();
            } else {
                $scope.open();
            }
          };
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
          var picker = {
                  open : function () {
                      timepickerState.closeAll();
                      scope.isOpen = true;
                  },
                  close: function () {
                      scope.isOpen = false;
                  }

          }
          timepickerState.addPicker(picker);

          scope.open = picker.open;
          scope.close = picker.close;

          scope.$watch("disabled", function(value) {
            scope.disabledInt = angular.isUndefined(scope.disabled)? false : scope.disabled;
          });

          scope.$watch("inputTime", function(value) {
            if (!scope.inputTime) {
              element.addClass('has-error');
            } else {
              element.removeClass('has-error');
            }

          });

          element.bind('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          });

          $document.bind('click', function(event) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
                scope.isOpen = false;
            });
          });

        },
        template : "<input type='text' class='form-control' ng-model='inputTime' ng-disabled='disabledInt' time-format show-meridian='showMeridian' ng-focus='open()' />"
            + "  <div class='input-group-btn' ng-class='{open:isOpen}'> "
            + "    <button type='button' ng-disabled='disabledInt' class='btn btn-default ' ng-class=\"{'btn-primary':isOpen}\" data-toggle='dropdown' ng-click='toggle()'> "
            + "        <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></i></button> "
            + "          <div class='dropdown-menu pull-right'> "
            + "            <timepicker ng-model='inputTime' show-meridian='showMeridian'></timepicker> "
            + "           </div> " + "  </div>"
      };
});
```

Comment: Did you load the module into your app dependency? in the `angular.module('myApp',['timepickerPop']`

Comment: argh... and I even looked at the app.js with the module deps and thought nuttin bout it :P